# "Connection in use" error in GCP app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform

I am new to GCP App engine. I am trying to make web server using flask on App engine. I tested the version of my code on localhost and it is working fine. But when I am trying to deploy it in the App Engine of GCP it is giving me this strange error "app logs". 
[error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBntu.jpg)

Here is my code for the flask

```
app.run(threaded = True, host='127.0.0.1', port=80)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: standard or flexible environment?

Comment: standard environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to call `app.run()` in your `main.py` file -- App Engine will do that for you. Simply initialize the `app` variable in this file instead.